# Database for counting page accesses

Tags: mysql, analytics, counting, nosql

So let's say I have a site with appx. 40000 articles.
What  Im hoping to do is record the number of page visits per each article overtime.

Basically the end goal is to be able to visualize via graph the number of lookups for any article between any period of time.
Here's an example: https://books.google.com/ngrams

I've began thinking about mysql data structure -> but my brain tells me it's probably not the right task for mysql. Almost seems like I'd need to use some specific nosql analytics solution.

Could anyone advice what DB is the right fit for this job?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is fine. It supports `UPDATE` statements that guarantee your count is correct rather than just eventual consistency.

Although most people will just use a log file, and process this on-demand. Unless you are Google scale, that will be fast enough.

There exist many tools for this, often including some very efficient specialized data structures such as RDDs that you won't find in any database. Why don't you just use them?

Comment: "SQL is fine. It supports UPDATE". But im talking about time series data. I can't simply update a counter -> that would only give me a total number of visits per article. I need to be able to get a number of visits per specific timeframe ex: March to April and be able to generate nice graph for it.

Comment: Use an index on the time column? SQL servers are very good at selecting and aggregating ranges. Or use RDDs.